# Referring to gwt module with new `module.gwt.xml` file

Tags: maven, gwt

Using the new maven archetypes for gwt in https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes I found that gwt modules `.gwt.xml` files can be left *outside* the `java` folder in the standard maven hierarchy. Yet, the example only uses this structure for a package that is directly used by a host page.

I wonder if there's a way to reuse such a module from another gwt module by means if `<inherits/>` clause. And if so, what would be that way. i.e. what name has to be used when referring to that module from an `<inherits/>` clause.

Module that I need to inherit

```
    ./pom.xml
    ./src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/mymodule/MyComponent.java
    ./src/main/module.gwt.xml
```

Main module

```
    ./pom.xml
    ./src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/AppEntryPoint.java
    ./src/main/module.gwt.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module name is specified in the plugin configuration (https://git.io/vMEzd), anyways, if the dependency is a gwt-lib package and the dependant module is a gwt-app package, the maven plugin automatically add the inherit line. This example (https://git.io/vMEgt) depends on a shared lib which is automatically added in the final gwt.xml module.